# iOS: Conditionally load a view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to conditionally load a view controller from the App Delegate?

So for example, can this be done?

```
    if (hasUserSignedUp) {
        nav = [[navController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [window addSubview:nav.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else {
        su = [[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [window addSubview:su.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this should be voted down; while the question is also technical in nature, it's also a philosophical question that cuts to the heart of what an `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method is responsible for.

Comment: I did try it. Otherwise I wouldn't need to post the question. If you don't have anything useful to say, THEN DON"T SAY IT ALL! Common manners really.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @edc1591 on this one.  If you mean something other than "will this compile and run" then you need to say so.  We can't guess at unstated questions.

Comment: @rosst400 If you did try it, then why did you post a question? If you encountered some sort of error then you should state that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite convinient, there are no restrictions for you to do this.

But you'd better set rootViewController instead of adding a view, i think.

```
self.window.rootViewController = nav;//or su;
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is certainly possible, what's probably a better idea is to load your navigation controller in both cases and, depending on if they've signed up, use a different root view controller.

```
if (hasUserSignedUp) {
    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
}
else {
    su = [[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:su];
}

[window addSubview:nav.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The app delete should create the root of the view hierarchy, and from there, you can manipulate it as you see fit.

If I were you, I would use the code above and, once they have signed in or signed up, push the regular root view controller and then modify the nav stack stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];

double delayInSeconds = 0.5f;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.navigationController.viewControllers.lastObject];
});
```

This isn't the cleanest way to do this (`dispatch_after`), but you see how it's done. Make sure the rootViewController has `hidesBackButton` set to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

set rootViewController is good habit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you certainly can do it that way.